# Better way to rewrite conditional sum - Query merging

Tags: mysql

The idea is to get all data for a time frame
    We want to do a query that shows everything related with a employee for this month. There is a total of 7 queries to merge into one pivot result.

```
General where date clause as some tables consists of two dates start and ends
start >= this month_starting_date
end <= this month_ending_date

example
start >= 2017-11-01 AND
end <= 2017-11-30

Single dates

date >= 2017-11-01 AND
date <= 2017-11-30
```

Database schemas ( rest is in the example )

**employees**

```
/*

    Display the employees table
    ------------------
    PK_worker | Name
    ------------------
       1      | Test
    ------------------
    This would be the main table
*/
SELECT PK_worker,
       concat(name,' ',surname) AS name
FROM employees;
```

**employees_delegations**

```
/*
    Display the employees_delegations table
    Get employees delegation cost by given date range
    ------------------
    PK_worker | to_hand_cost
    ------------------
       1      | 500.00
    ------------------
    This data should be included in the main table
*/
SELECT PK_worker,
       sum(cost) AS to_hand_cost
FROM employees_to_hand /* WHERE d_start d_end is within this month */
GROUP BY PK_worker;
```

**employees_delegations**

```
/*
    Display the employees_delegations table
    Get employees delegation cost by given date range
    ------------------
    PK_worker | delegation_cost
    ------------------
       1      | 500.00
    ------------------
*/
SELECT PK_worker,
       sum(cost) AS delegation_cost
FROM employees_delegations /* WHERE d_start d_end is within this month */
GROUP BY PK_worker;
```

**employees_salaries**

```
/*
    Display the employees_salaries table
    Get employees salaries by given date range
    ------------------
    PK_worker | payout_amount
    ------------------
       1      | 500.00
    ------------------
*/
SELECT PK_worker,
       sum(gross) AS payout_amount
FROM employees_salaries /* WHERE mmonth(start) payout_date(end) is within this month */
GROUP BY PK_worker;
```

**employees_deductions**

```
/*  
    Display the employees_deductions table
    Get employees deductions by given date range
    ------------------
    PK_worker | deduction_cost
    ------------------
       1      | 500.00
    ------------------
*/ 
SELECT PK_worker,
       sum(cost) AS deduction_cost
FROM employees_deductions /* WHERE dwhen is within this month */
GROUP BY PK_worker;
```

**Desired result**

I would like to merge thous queries into one, My final query seems to be ok but there is a thing missing, *How can I get all the where clauses in the final version?* Perhaps the **Join's** should be a subquery? or is there a smoother solution

```
/*
    Final output should look like this
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK_worker | name | expense_cost | to_hand_cost | delegation_cost | payout_amount | deduction_cost | extra_cost | agreement_amount
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1      | a1 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
       2      | b2 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    And preferably it should have one where clause if possible to give the date range


*/

    SELECT 
   employees.PK_worker, 
/*concat(employees.name,' ',employees.surname) AS name, ---- somehow I cant add this*/ 
coalesce(sum(employees_to_hand.cost),0) AS to_hand_cost,
coalesce(sum(employees_delegations.cost),0) AS delegation_cost,
coalesce(sum(employees_salaries.gross),0) AS payout_amount,
coalesce(sum(employees_deductions.cost),0) AS deduction_cost,
coalesce(sum(employees_extras.cost),0) AS extra_cost,
coalesce(sum(employees_agreement.to_payout),0) AS agreement_amount,
coalesce(sum(expenses.cost_gross),0) AS expense_cost
    FROM employees
    LEFT JOIN employees_delegations ON employees_delegations.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
    LEFT JOIN employees_to_hand ON employees_to_hand.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
    LEFT JOIN employees_salaries ON employees_salaries.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
    LEFT JOIN employees_deductions ON employees_deductions.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
    LEFT JOIN employees_extras ON employees_extras.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
    LEFT JOIN employees_agreement ON employees_agreement.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
    LEFT JOIN expenses ON expenses.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
    GROUP BY employees.PK_worker
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Mysql playground, mcve example** : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RvfD3uA4cSSVgmhoP2co6/7

Comment: Go to stackoverflow.com and follow the [mysql] [pivot-table] tags for lots examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's possible to have multiple rows (from multiple tables) match a given `PK_worker` value, we'll end up with a cartesian product if we join all of these rows via the proposed query (`select ... sum() ... from ... left join ... left join ...`); this in turn would lead to the various `sum()` calls being applied against duplicate values (ie, we'll get larger sum's than expected).

To address this issue we'll need to look at a redesign of the main query; in particular we'll need to pull the various `left join` statements into the individual `select` clauses, eg:

```
select employees.PK_worker,
       concat(employees.name,' ',employees.surname)                    AS name,

       (select coalesce(sum(employees_to_hand.cost),0)
        from   employees_to_hand
        where  employees_to_hand.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
        and    employees_to_hand.reg_date between ....)                AS to_hand_cost,
    ....
```

As for how to add the date ranges to the query ...

---

One idea would be to add a derived table that generates your desired start/end dates, eg:

```
select employees.PK_worker,
       concat(employees.name,' ',employees.surname)                    AS name,

       (select coalesce(sum(employees_to_hand.cost),0)
        from   employees_to_hand
        where  employees_to_hand.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
        and    employees_to_hand.reg_date between d.dstart and d.dend) AS to_hand_cost,
    ....
from employees

JOIN (select  str_to_date('10/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y') as dstart,
              str_to_date('11/30/2017','%m/%d/%Y') as dend) as d         
...
```

Here's a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5FtV24czfAfUiE1dj5EeYt/10) for the complete query using a derived table.

---

Another idea would be to set a pair of user-defined variables upfront and then reference them in the follow-on query, eg:

```
set @dstart = str_to_date('10/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y'),
    @dend   = str_to_date('11/30/2017','%m/%d/%Y');

select employees.PK_worker,
       concat(employees.name,' ',employees.surname)                    AS name,

       (select coalesce(sum(employees_to_hand.cost),0)
        from   employees_to_hand
        where  employees_to_hand.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
        and    employees_to_hand.reg_date between @dstart and @dend)   AS to_hand_cost,
    ....
from employees
```

Here's a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5FtV24czfAfUiE1dj5EeYt/11) for the complete query using the user-defined variables.

---

And then there's the combination of the derived table and variable solutions:

```
select employees.PK_worker,
       concat(employees.name,' ',employees.surname)                    AS name,

       (select coalesce(sum(employees_to_hand.cost),0)
        from   employees_to_hand
        where  employees_to_hand.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
        and    employees_to_hand.reg_date between @dstart and @dend)   AS to_hand_cost,
    ....
from employees

JOIN (select  @dstart := str_to_date('10/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y'),
              @dend   := str_to_date('11/30/2017','%m/%d/%Y')) d         
...
```

Here's a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5FtV24czfAfUiE1dj5EeYt/13) for the complete query using the combo derived-table/variable solution.

---

NOTES:

- was able to add your employee name to the results by also adding the name statement to the `group by` clause
- had to modify a few of the column names in your sample queries to match the column names from the `create table` commands
- wasn't sure which datetime column (`pdate`, `added`) to use for the `expenses` table so I picked one (`pdate`); modify accordingly

Comment: Will study this tomorrow in the morning. Cheers

Comment: Is it possible that it counts wrongly? Check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5FtV24czfAfUiE1dj5EeYt/4 , I think other values might be off aswell any idea why ( as you see query 1 returns 300 and the big query 7800, where the total sum of all values isn't even close to that for all workers ) ? Just check the single query for a worker

Comment: **arg** ... silly me ... I took your incomplete select as valid and built on top of that; because there are multiple rows matching from multiple tables, and the only join criteria is based on the employees table, we're getting some cartesian products when combining the matches from all of the tables; see this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5FtV24czfAfUiE1dj5EeYt/12) for a simple example; I've updated the answer (and fiddles) to address the cartesian product issue

Comment: Well it works but the code itself looks nasty :}

Comment: you obviously haven't been around SQL for very long! :-)  this query is rather tame compared to some of the convoluted, nightmare-inducing queries I've seen over the years

Comment: Id like to see a nasty one :D

Comment: Oh is it possible to do maths on the aliases? An extra column for example add agreement_amount + to_hand_cost

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192232/alias-summing-in-mysql ;)

Comment: I've provided an answer for that other question (simple math on the sums); also includes an updated (working) db-fiddle