# Alias summing in mysql

Tags: mysql

My query looks like this

```
select employees.PK_worker,
       concat(employees.name,' ',employees.surname)                    AS name,

       (select coalesce(sum(employees_to_hand.cost),0)
        from   employees_to_hand
        where  employees_to_hand.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
        and    employees_to_hand.reg_date between @dstart and @dend)   AS to_hand_cost,

       (select coalesce(sum(employees_delegations.cost),0) 
        from   employees_delegations
        where  employees_delegations.PK_worker = employees.PK_worker
        and    employees_delegations.dstart between @dstart and @dend) AS delegation_cost
FROM employees

join (select  @dstart := str_to_date('10/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y'),
              @dend   := str_to_date('11/30/2017','%m/%d/%Y')) d

order by 1;
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do some basic summing for instance (`to_hand_cost` + `delegation_cost`) as simple_sum I assume it might be not possible but repeating the selects again to get the values seems overwhelming. Got any suggestions?

**Mysql playground mcve** : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5FtV24czfAfUiE1dj5EeYt/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two inner tables should have `INDEX(PK_worker, reg_date, cost)` and `INDEX(PK_worker, dstart, cost)`.

Plan A:

The following *may* help, and it *may* depend on what version of MySQL you are running:

```
JOIN ( SELECT str_to_date('10/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y') AS start,
              str_to_date('11/30/2017','%m/%d/%Y') AS end ) AS d
```

and then use `start` and `end` instead of `@start` and `@end`.

Rationale:  `@variables` are sometimes not well optimized.

Plan B:  (But this requires 5.6, perhaps 5.7 - see the `EXPLAIN` for "auto-key".)

```
SELECT e.PK_worker,
   concat(e.name,' ',e.surname)   AS name,
    FROM employees AS e
    JOIN ( SELECT PK_worker,
                  coalesce(sum(cost),0) AS to_hand_cost
              FROM employees_to_hand
              WHERE ...
                AND reg_date BETWEEN start AND end
              GROUP BY 1 ) AS ethc
      ON e.PK_worker = ethc.PK_worker
    JOIN ( ... )  AS edc
      ON ...
    ORDER BY 1;

INDEX(reg_date, PK_worker, cost)
```

Rationale:  Calculating all the costs in one pass over the secondary tables is probably faster than one employee at a time.  Hopefully it is enough faster than the cost of automatically creating `INDEX(PK_worker)` after generating the 'derived' table.  The different index is a guess as to what would work better for this.

Thanks for dbfiddle, but in *this* situation, some of the optimizations depend on the size of the table, distribution of the values (esp `reg_date`, and the version of MySQL).

Comment: objective is to sum costs across a given date range, but Plan B appears to be summing costs across entire tables; since db-fiddle.com allows for MySQL versions 5.5, 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0, could you provide a working fiddle that implements your proposed design?

Comment: @markp - Oops.  Hopefully I have now fixed the code appropriately (in Plan B)

Comment: a bit better :-), but still looking for how you feed `start` and `end` (from a derived table?) into the `ethc` derived table ... ?  a working db-fiddle that generates one of the cost columns would help fill in the blanks for the complete picture

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to:

- continue to use the `@dstart` and `@dend` variables to designate our date/search range (couldn't get derived table columns - eg, `d.dstart` - to be used in sibling derived tables; this is normal behavior in other RDBMSs, but not sure about MySQL)
- convert the select/sub-queries into derived tables
- `left join` `employees` with these derived tables (since not all employees are guaranteed to have all 7x costs for a given date range)
- this gives us summed costs (by worker) at the top level of the query, so from here we can do some simple math on the sums

Pulling this all together, a shortened query for the proposed summation (`to_hand_cost` + `delegation_cost`) looks like:

```
select e.PK_worker,
       concat(e.name,' ',e.surname)                        as name,
       coalesce(eth.sum_cost,0)                            as to_hand_cost,
       coalesce(ed1.sum_cost,0)                            as delegation_cost,

       coalesce(eth.sum_cost,0) + coalesce(ed1.sum_cost,0) as simple_sum

from employees e

join (select  @dstart := str_to_date('10/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y'),
              @dend   := str_to_date('11/30/2017','%m/%d/%Y')) as d

left
join (select PK_worker,
             sum(cost) as sum_cost
      from   employees_to_hand
      where  reg_date between @dstart and @dend
      group by PK_worker) as eth

on   eth.PK_worker = e.PK_worker

left
join (select PK_worker,
             sum(cost) as sum_cost
      from   employees_delegations
      where  dstart between @dstart and @dend
      group by PK_worker) as ed1

on   ed1.PK_worker = e.PK_worker

order by 1;
```

Here's an updated [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5FtV24czfAfUiE1dj5EeYt/18) for the complete query.  A quick review appears to show the same results as the original db-fiddle.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did :) And also I left the old selects in selects for some of them. I also converted it into a procedure, is the part join (select @d ..) required while using a procedure? the @ vars transformed into p0 p1

Comment: if you'll be using stored proc input parameters for the date range then you can eliminate the @variable/derived-table, and (of course) replace the @variable references in the rest of the query with your proc params